# How to prevent AdSense ad to load advertiser website in the same window

Tags: adsense

I want when someone clicks the Google AdSense ad, the advertiser's website open in a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its against [adsense policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354740?hl=en). As far as I know, only selected publishers allowed to do so, usually the big websites with huge traffics.